# GMP conditional

Tags: gmp

I'm using libgmp to create a simple program. I can gmp_printf all gmp integers so I know that these are initialised and assigned correctly. The problem occurs when i try a simple if-else conditional.

```
mpz_t n;
mpz_t c;
mpz_t m;

mpz_init(n);
mpz_init(c);
mpz_init(m); 

mpz_set_str(c, "2", 10);
mpz_set_str(n, "2038074744", 10);

mpz_mod(m, n, c);

gmp_printf("\n%Zd\n%Zd\n%Zd\n", n, c, m);

if(m == 0)
{
printf("number is even\n");
}
else
{
printf("number is odd\n");
}
```

The actual number prints as 0 but the else printf is always displayed.

```
2038074744
2
0
number is odd
```

Is there some way of getting this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly compare to `m` since `m` is (roughly speaking) a pointer. You need to use the comparison functions included in GMP. See http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Comparisons.html#Integer-Comparisons

Answer (score 0):

Use `mpz_cmp` instead of `m == 0`:

```
if(mpz_cmp(m,0)  == 0)
    printf("number is even\n");
else
    printf("number is odd\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer "*You can't directly compare to m since m is (roughly speaking) a pointer*" is almost correct, `m` is a `mpz_t` type which is a struct defined in `gmp.h`:

```
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;
  int _mp_size;
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;  /* Pointer to the limbs.  */
} __mpz_struct;

typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

But you should use `mpz_cmp_ui(m,0UL)` or `mpz_cmp_si(m,0L)`, and *not* the suggested `mpz_cmp` in the other answer, as it compares `m` with a zero pointer as explained before.